# Centering a form vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to CSS coding and I'm having hard time working out how to vertically and horizontally align my form within the page. I've tried putting it in a div and putting the following CSS but it stayed in the top left:

```
verticaly-align: middle;
align: center;
```

This is the code I'm working with:

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q28WR/18/embedded/result/
**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q28WR/18/

Can anyone help with getting this form sitting in the right place?

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked zillion times before. Did you [google](https://www.google.be/search?q=css+center+div+vertically+and+horizontally&rlz=1C1CHFX_nlBE448BE448&oq=css+center+div+vertically+&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3j62.7546j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#rlz=1C1CHFX_nlBE448BE448&sclient=psy-ab&q=css+center+form+vertically+and+horizontally&oq=css+center+form+vertically+and+horizontally&gs_l=serp.3...10733.11297.0.11776.5.5.0.0.0.0.130.515.3j2.5.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.psy-ab.FqOp3imbm-4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZG4&fp=cf66d858ab41a766&biw=1920&bih=955) it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Center Forms Vertically and Horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890126/css-center-forms-vertically-and-horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to center it horizontally:

```
#wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Someone with more experience can add the vertically centered answer to this.

PS: this is probably asked very often, you should dig deeper and post your results before asking a question.